# Windows 10: Enable system-wide smooth scrolling

Tags: windows-10, mouse, touchpad, scrolling, dell-precision

This question is a bit different from others that I have found, because the solutions to them have always been "change the scroll setting to 1 line at a time". I won't be satisfied by that. I don't want slower scrolling; I want smooth scrolling.

I want per-pixel scrolling, not per-line scrolling. That means even if it is set to scroll, let's say, an arbitrary 5 lines at a time, that scroll should be animated to look smooth and not jumpy on the screen.

Basically, like browsers, code editors, and rich text browsers do it, but everywhere. I already have taken apart my mouse and smashed down that little metal tab that makes it click, I hate the click. I thought the lack of smooth scrolling was a hardware limitation, but since this didn't fix it, it must not be.

Applications always seem to have smooth scrolling when I use my precision touchpad. I would like to emulate that with a physical mouse wheel as well. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not every application can be made to scroll smoothly in Windows with a single, global, Windows setting.

- For Windows *list-boxes*, open the *Performance Options* CPL and check *Smooth-scroll list boxes*.

[image: Performance Options Scrolling]

Each application has it's own smooth-scrolling setting. For example:

- In [*Firefox*](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/), in *about:preferences*, search on *scrol*, and set *Use smooth scrolling*.

[image: Firefox Smooth Scrolling]

In [*Sumatra PDF*](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader) reader, open *Advanced Options* to edit *SumatraPDF-settings.txt* and set *SmoothScroll=true*.

[image: Sumatra PDF Smooth Scrolling]